# ReactJS - What is the best way to push data in an array within an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, push

I wanted to push a data inside an object(orders). the orders have array inside which is products, parts and prints. I want to push data in the prints only. Meaning I have 2 buttons, the 1st button will push data of all the orders while the 2nd button will only push a portion of orders, which is prints. you can see that the prints is under orders. Can you suggest a way on how can I do this?

below is the array of orders that I have. Now I only want to push a data into orders.prints

```
          orders: [{
            product: {
              pType: '',
              name: '',
              brand: '',
              color: '',
              files: []
            },
            parts: [],
            prints: [{
              name: '',
              width: '',
              height: '',
              colors: ''
            }],
            breakdown: [{
              size: '',
              quantity: 0
            }]
          }]
```

Comment: can you simplify the question?

Comment: @kharandziuk How Can I add more data in prints array only which is inside an array, orders specifically?

Comment: I mean remove all the unnecessary details from your question and somebody will answer it.

Comment: What about `orders[0].prints.push({})`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by adding value in orders to set the index. orders[0]

```
onAddPrint = () => {
    var newPrints = this.state.orders;
    newPrints[0].prints.push({
              name: 'Test',
              width: 'Test',
              height: 'Test',
              colors: 
            });

    this.setState({
      orders: this.state.orders.splice(0, 1, newPrints)
    });
  }
```